# Facebook Album Photo upload

Tags: php, facebook

I want to try an upload a photo to my already created album via PHP facebook api.
$aid is the album Id which i get from database .. $file_name is the file path

```
$facebook->api('me/'.$aid.'/photos',"POST",array('source'=>'@'.$file_name,'access_token'=>$facebook->getAccessToken()));
```

but this is giving an error

```
Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Can only call this method on valid test users for your app
```

If i use this without the access token and the "me" in the start of the first param it gives

```
Uncaught OAuthException: (#324) Requires upload file
```

i have already used this in the same site and it worked there, that was it created an album and uploaded pics without any issue.. but i do not know what is the issue here
please point out my mistakes

Answer (score 0):

if in your database design your aid field is integer, this can be reason for the error. You should save $aid as string.